# Resolution of ImageList Icons are not clear in TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, imagelist

Resolution for `ImageList` which is being used for `TabControl`
Icons if the TabControl Draw mode is OwnerDrawFixed is not clear and causing
some issues with the different backgrounds. If the background of the Rectangle container is having SolidBrush, The Image will be OK. Otherwise it will be disturbed.

Is there any good way to draw the image in High resolution?

Comment: Share an image of rendered tabs. What are Icon types, are they png? and What are the size?

Comment: it is png and the size is 24x24. I'll share some pics also. But tell me is there a problem if I used png?? @RezaAghaei

Comment: No, there is no problem, Check this: **1-** Set `ColorDepth` property to 32 bit **2-** Set `ImageSize` property to `24, 24` **3-** Then add your 24x24 images to your `ImageList`

Comment: I'll try and let u know. Thanks you deserve all the respect @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding images to `ImageList` consider:

- Set `ColorDepth` property to `Depth32Bit` for png images.
- Set `ImageSize` property to your original images size, in your case `24,24`

Then add images to your image list.

Changing these properties after adding images will result in low quality images.

Comment: So, do you mean that if I added the pictures with another settings like for example ColorDepth=Depth8Bit. and tried later on to modify this property to ColorDepth=Depth32Bit, The Image will stay in low quaality?

Comment: @Emad-Developer Yes this will result low quality images. You should perform settings first, and then add images.

Comment: It's because it stores images with the settings that you set and when you set lower bit depth or size, and add images, then when you change higher bit depth or size, it changes existing low quality image to higher bit depth or size and this will result in low quality image.