# .Png images get converted to grayscale when used in ImageList

Tags: c#, image

I'm writing a C# windows forms application and I need some images to serve as icons in a `TreeListListView`
I'm using an `ImageList` and add .pgn images to it.
The weird thing is that after restarting Visual Studio, my image has lost most of it's color
[image]
Some of the properties of the image such as **RawFormat** are also different after restarting VS
[image]
As can be seen in this enlarged image there is almost no color left after restarting. This "grayscale" image is also what I see in my application.
[image]
I'm looking for an answer that explains what I'm seeing, and that offers a workaround
The ImageList itself has the following properties:
[image]

Comment: just curious, what does that resolution 95,9104 mean?

Comment: Never seens anything like that. Are the colors changed just in VS or also in the application?

Comment: @TaW also in the application. I wouldn't have cared if it was only in Visual Studio?

Comment: @urlreader I guess it means "almost 96". It's the value it gets after selecting the image from the file system.

Comment: What are the properties of the ImageList?

Comment: Yes, known issue about the `ImageList`. Make sure you do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33469823/14171304) and don't change the `ImageList` properties after adding your images. Or a better route is, keep the images in the project's resources, add them to the `ImageList` at runtime in the constructor of its container.

Comment: Are the resulting images really greyscale or are the color just smudged? Long shot: The dpi error (which it certainly is) may be the source of this. You can correct it by setting the dpi resolution before addding the images to the image list.. - And: Yes, adding images to the list will create a new version and you should not change the imgList settings afterwards or the quality will degrade.

Comment: @Steeeve I've posted the properties of the ImageList

Comment: The properties of the ImageList were the key. Changing `ColorDepth` to `Depth24bit` resolved the issue. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: ColorDepth 8bit doesn't match 32bpp of your images. Try to change it accordingly to your png images used.

Comment: @Steeeve, yes exactly, that was it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ColorDepth` property of the `ImageList`. Having it at the value `Depth8bit` converts the images to 8 bit color, and this is only visible in VS after restarting.

[image]

Changing the property to `Depth32bit` and then adding the images again solved the problem.

[image]

The images now show their true colors in the application

[image]